# Problem with the icons of cv_7 modern cv

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to edit my cv using moderncv package, cv_7 style, but when I compile I get the following result for my CV.
Why can't I get the proper icons for the phone, mail etc... ?
Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

%\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

\firstname{Pauline} % Your first name 
\familyname{} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{}
\address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@smith.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{additional information}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `cv_7` style in [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). Could you provide the community with a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than the little image showing the output? Also, for correct results of symbols that may use the [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) symbols (which `moderncv` does, I think), you need to compile using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I added the latex code I use. I compile using XeLaTeX. I have found the code in the website LaTeX Templates Modern CV and Cover Letters (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter)

Comment: Using your preamble snippet together with the online [writeLaTeX template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) and compiling with either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX produces the desired symbol output. It may be that your distribution requires updating (see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)). Once you've done that and the problem is still there, include `\listfiles` in your preamble and report back on the package versions you're using (see [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've followed your advice and updated my distribution, but the problem remains. Then I included \listfiles and looked at the log file but I really don't understand anything... I wonder whether or not I should re-install LaTeX on my computer, because my computer was repaired a few weeks ago, and since this moment I often have trouble using LaTeX...

Comment: An update of the distribution should have solved the problem. My suggestion is to include the contents in your `.log` after `**File List**` in your current post. That would allow us to see the packages you're using (and their versions) and then compare that with what I (we) have. You may also elaborate on the type of warnings/errors you receive.

Comment: I eventually re-installed some packages using TeX Live Utility and it worked ! Thanks a lot for your support and your suggestion to see How do I update my TeX distribution?, because I didn't know the application TeX Live Utility. Thanks again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the usage of a not up-to-date distribution. After updating problem was solved ...

Comment: I'm having the same problem using basictex for mac (fresh install). @Pauline which packages did you install to make it work? Thanks